# XML datatype in column to find existing of values

Tags: oracle

I have issues in find the rows in table having datatype as XMLType and I am looking for Name 'PrimeSub' and Value as 'Y'. Thanks

```
<attributes>  
  <upper_lvl_ver_desc>
    <Name>AABB</Name>
    <Description>pkListValue</Description>
    <Value/>
  </upper_lvl_ver_desc>
  <upper_lvl_ver_desc>
    <Name>GL_PS_ALLOWED</Name>
    <Description>pkListValue</Description>
    <Value/>
  </upper_lvl_ver_desc>
  <upper_lvl_ver_desc>
    <Name>PrimeSub</Name>
    <Description>pkListValue</Description>
    <Value>Y</Value>
  </upper_lvl_ver_desc>
</attributes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your table name or structure, so here I'm using `mytable` as the table name and `xmlcol` as the xmltype column. The WITH clause at the top is just to provide the test data.

```
with mytable as (select xmltype('<attributes>  
  <upper_lvl_ver_desc>
    <Name>AABB</Name>
    <Description>pkListValue</Description>
    <Value/>
  </upper_lvl_ver_desc>
  <upper_lvl_ver_desc>
    <Name>GL_PS_ALLOWED</Name>
    <Description>pkListValue</Description>
    <Value/>
  </upper_lvl_ver_desc>
  <upper_lvl_ver_desc>
    <Name>PrimeSub</Name>
    <Description>pkListValue</Description>
    <Value>Y</Value>
  </upper_lvl_ver_desc>
</attributes>') as xmlcol from dual)
-- query starts here
select xmlcol
from mytable
inner join XMLTable('/attributes/upper_lvl_ver_desc' PASSING mytable.xmlcol
                COLUMNS c_name varchar2(50) PATH 'Name',
                        c_value varchar2(1) PATH 'Value') atts
on c_name = 'PrimeSub' and c_value = 'Y'
;
```

This method might seem a bit counter-intuitive, but it's one way Oracle recommends doing it. You join the XML column as a pseudo-table using the XMLTable function, transforming it into relational data which can easily be manipulated in SQL. [You can read more about it here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_rel_views.htm#ADXDB4134).

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine ..... when I discussed with my lead in development table  column XMLtype STORE AS SECUREFILE BINARY XML whereas in prod database it stored as CLOB and this query has issues he is saying ...any idea about his

Comment: Probably you just need to cast the clob to xmltype. In the query above you could change the PASSING clause to `PASSING xmltype(mytable.xmlcol)` and I think that should fix it.

Comment: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XMLTYPE'
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s" ... How about below query this also works fine for me : SELECT xmlcol
FROM mytable
WHERE EXTRACT(xmlcol, '//attributes/upper_lvl_ver_desc/Name/text()').getStringVal() LIKE '%PrimeSub%'
AND EXTRACT(xmlcol, '//attributes/upper_lvl_ver_desc/Value/text()').getStringVal() LIKE '%Y%';

Comment: Sure, go for it! Oracle deprecated EXTRACT in 12c so I try to avoid it but *shrug* if it works, why not use it